# How to make plots in python like the sleep schedule plot in iOS Health app

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to analyze my sleep data from iOS Health app.
My data is parsed from exported xml file and stored in `Pandas.DataFrame`. The columns contain **Start datetime** and **End datetime** in Pandas `datetime` type. I want to make the plot like [the sleep schedule plot in iOS Health app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsIcQ.png), which is date vs time "scatter bar chart". I'd like to know if I can use `matplotlib` to do so. Or there are some other python packages I can use.

Especially, each day may contain multiple records. Also, some records may start in one day and end in the next day.

Currently, the closest package I found is [time_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/time_chart) in Flutter. But I cannot find how to do it in python.

Comment: looks like a Gantt chart, try using broken_barh() function in matplotlib

Comment: @ChrisSeeling Sorry, I updated the question to make it more clear: 
"Especially, each day may contain multiple records. Also, some records may start in one day and end in the next day."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detailed styling aside, the code below outlines an approach you could take

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot()

width = 0.5

# [day_index, start_time, duration, type]
sleep_array = [[0,10,200, 0], [1,20,20, 0], [1, 50,10, 1],  [2,40,180, 1], [2,50,100, 0]]

color_dict = {0:'darkturquoise', 1:'turquoise'}

for e in sleep_array:
    rect = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((e[0], e[1]),width, e[2],color =color_dict[e[3]])
    ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.xlim([-0.5, 10]); plt.ylim([-0.5, 250])

plt.show()
```

Gives:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to matplotlib.patches, which I didn't know!!! I think this is a great starting point and I probably should separate the record that has different start and end date into two separate records before plotting it.

Comment: Thank you so much and I've successfully created the plot based on your answer! Also, I've summarized my steps in: https://blog.gwlab.page/how-to-parse-xml-file-exported-from-apple-ios-health-app-and-make-a-sleep-schedule-plot-using-60c652697c81

Comment: Very nice write-up in the blog.